# Using ADOX in Visual Studio 2010 flags an error

Tags: c#, .net, database, oledb, ado

```
Table table = new Table();
table.Name = "TestResults";
Column column = new Column();
column.Name = "SerialNumber";
column.Type = DataTypeEnum.adVarChar;
column.DefinedSize = 14;
table.Columns.Append(column);
catalog.Tables.Append(table); --- flags "Object is no longer valid" exception
```

What's the root cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because you haven't specified an OLE DB provider, at least not in the code sample you've given. Add a reference to the ADODB type library, then add this code before yours:

```
Connection conn = new Connection();
string connectionString = "Provider='Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'; Data Source='path-to-some-database-file.mdb'";
conn.Open(connectionString, "userid", "password", -1);
catalog.ActiveConnection = conn;
```

For my code, I had to change the column type to adVarWChar because [Jet 4.0 doesn't support adVarChar](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/266302). But you're probably using a different database.

I tested this with a .mdb file I had, and the new table was successfully added (I know for sure because when I ran it again, I got the error "Table 'TestResults' already exists."